# Bootstrap 4: How to create a center vertical scrollable <div> using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

base on my question, Basically I want to make my webpage like below:

[image]

The red box means that the div that can scrollable and the div size is according to the content size. Meanwhile, The main background (that man)and the navbar is fixed and no scrollable.

Below is my current code:

```
<body id="header">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: black;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style = "font-weight: 600; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" href="#">Dr. Lim Wee Chai</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 600; font-family: Arial;" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">Philosophies & Values</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">Lifestyle</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">Top Glove</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">Future Vision</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style = "font-weight: 500;" href="#">Videos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br>

</body>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: you need a div with a fixed height and `overflow: scroll`

Comment: why you give us navbar HTML only, give us whole navbar and header code, we are here to help you but without code we cant help you

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, the flex properties can be usefull to achieve this. Bootstrap 4 makes great use of this in the [flex utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). To assemble this setup, the simplest form I've found so far:

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="my-component d-flex mx-auto align-self-center flex-column">
        <!-- some scrollable content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/0jwx75os/).

---

To explain all these classes let's break it down:

1. Make sure `html, body` have `height: 100%;`. This is required to generate a full height body. In turn the browser can now use this height to vertically center content
2. `.container` or `.container-fluid` with `.d-flex` and `.h-100` will make use of this body height to also stretch over the height of the screen.
3. `.my-component` now has a `height: 50vh` and `width: 50vw;` which is viewport height and -width and makes this component responsive. Also `overflow-y: auto;` to make it scrollable. Feel free to adjust this to your liking with media queries and so on.
4. It has also `.d-flex` to enable `.mx-auto` (horizontal center), `.align-self-center` (vertical center) and `.flex-column` to align the content properly

None of these utility classes can be omitted as they all work together.
Hopefully this is like you requested as the content of your "wrapper" isn't clear from the question.